# is there a more efficient (general) way to find a arg max for a function on a given interval in Python or R?

Tags: python, r

in math, arg max f(x) is to find a value of x to maximize the function f(x).

assume f(x) = sin(x), interval [0,], here is the code.

```
>>> x = []
>>> for i in range(1001):
...     x.append(i*np.pi/1000)
>>> sine_between_interval = np.sin(np.array(x))
>>> idx_max = np.argmax(sine_between_interval)
>>> idx_max
500
```

the question is, is there a more efficient (or general) way to find the solution value of a arg max on a given interval in Python or R?

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for. An analytic approach? Then take the derivative of the function. You will hit on the answer straight away. An numerical optimization approach? Something like Newton-Raphson or even steepest descent will give you reasonable convergence instead of sampling over the entire space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in R :

`optimize(function(x) sin(x), c(0, pi), maximum = TRUE)`

> $maximum
>
> [1] 1.570796
>
> $objective
>
> [1] 1

where objective is your argmax